# setinterval to reload php page unless "edit" button is clicked

Tags: jquery

right now I have an interval function in jquery that reloads a page every few seconds :

```
setInterval(function () {
$('div#tab2').load('morefour.php?doc=' + encodeURIComponent(ktitle));
}, 3000);
});
```

What I actually want to do now is if this input is clicked :

```
<input type='image' class='edit' src='edit.png'>
```

stop the setinterval function.

Comment: I think that there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: The trailing `});` seems out of place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setInterval` returns a handle you can use with `clearInterval` to cancel it. The handle will be a number greater than zero.

So save the handle from the `setInterval` call:

```
var handle = setInterval(function () {
    $('div#tab2').load('morefour.php?doc=' + encodeURIComponent(ktitle));
}, 3000);
```

...and then use it to cancel it if the button is pressed:

```
$("input.edit").click(function() {
    if (handle) {
        clearInterval(handle);
        handle = 0;
    }
});
```

Also note in that first snippet above, I've moved the interval parameter (`3000`) to where it should be (as Jared pointed out, you had it as a second parameter to `load`, where of course it should be a second parameter to `setInterval`).

Comment: You don't see something unusual about the `setInterval()` code?

Comment: @Jared: Ah, yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: Well, um... It should be removed, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.clearInterval() like [here](http://www.toutjavascript.com/reference/reference.php?iref=206).

Comment: It's usually considered a best practice to actually include the code in the answer instead of linking elsewhere. No telling how long that other site will last, so this answer's utility may become useless eventually. :)

Comment: Okay, I will do it for my future posts. I'm new in here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a flag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flag = true;
</script>
```

and change the `setInterval` statement to something like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (flag) {
        $('div#tab2').load('morefour.php?doc=' + encodeURIComponent(ktitle));
    }
}, 3000);
```

and change the flag in image `onclick`:

```
<input type='image' class='edit' src='edit.png' onclick="javascript:flag=false">
```